# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils from BaseClassLoader

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, dozer

I am getting the following **error**, while running my following code:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils from BaseClassLoader

at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.dozer.util.ResourceLoader.getResource(ResourceLoader.java:53)
at org.dozer.util.DefaultClassLoader.loadResource(DefaultClassLoader.java:44)
at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.loadGlobalSettings(GlobalSettings.java:116)
at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.<init>(GlobalSettings.java:67)
at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.<clinit>(GlobalSettings.java:46)
at org.dozer.stats.StatisticsManagerImpl.<init>(StatisticsManagerImpl.java:39)
at org.dozer.stats.GlobalStatistics.<init>(GlobalStatistics.java:29)
at org.dozer.stats.GlobalStatistics.<clinit>(GlobalStatistics.java:24)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.<clinit>(DozerBeanMapper.java:59)
```

Kindly, guide me to fix the problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42674106/5626568

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code seems to be using apace-commons-lang package .
Do add the jar from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6.
Chek for the version you are using. Add the jar to your lib folder/classpath.

Answer (score 16):

I received the same error, I added to my `pom.xml` file the following lines and worked fine after `maven install`:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- commons lang dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: In my situation, my pom.xml already has `commons-lang` dependency, but the tomcat server in Eclipse still fails to start. I checked the "tomcat server's lib directory" and found no `dozer` jar there. So I copy a `dozer` jar from `.m2` directory to there, and the problem solved.

Comment: for sbt use: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.4"

Answer (score 10):

In case you use maven and Ubuntu 14.04:

This can be caused by the maven version included in Ubuntu 14.04, and the workaround is to download the maven tarball from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and use that version instead of the default version provided by the distribution.

More information:
https://github.com/airbnb/chronos/issues/211

**EDIT:** You can also add a symlink to commons-lang.jar to avoid having to do a custom install ([Source](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/211#issuecomment-56861199) and @Shoham in the comments)

```
cd /usr/share/maven/lib
sudo ln -s ../../java/commons-lang.jar .
```

*Verify that the paths are correct on your system before attempting.  They should work for Ubuntu 14.04 OOTB, but always verify.*

Comment: Thanks! Can also be fixed by 'cd /usr/share/maven/lib
sudo ln -s ../../java/commons-lang.jar .'

Comment: Wasted hours trying to fix all sorts of maven problems. Finally saw this answer. Removed my `~/.m2` directory, removed Ubuntu's `mvn` that I had installed via `apt` and then installed mvn afresh from http://mvn.apache.org. Everything works now!

Answer (score 3):

Add the commons-lang jar either into WEB-INF/lib or server/lib

Answer (score 1):

include `commons-lang-<version>.jar` in your classpath

Comment: Hi,I have added commons-lang3-3.1, and Dozer jars to class path. But i'm still getting below exception: 15:22:52,730 SEVERE [ContainerResponse] The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper
 at com.ingenico.atlas.b2b.helper.DozerHelper.map(DozerHelper.java:13)

Comment: @AmitKumar Looks like you are missing something on the classpath.  Seems a dependency of com.ingenico.atlas.b2b.helper.DozerHelper.map is missing, class org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in latest version of IntelliJ Community Edition (`idea-IC-13.224.1` or version 14) along with `apache-maven 3.2.3`.

Adding missing jar (`commons-lang-2.6.jar`) in `$IDEA_HOME/plugins/maven/lib/maven3` folder seems to fix it.