# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

Tags: java, apache, maven, dependencies, apache-commons

I'm trying to run the sample project with [this](https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment) library and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

    org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

    at com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.enums.EmvCardScheme.<init>(EmvCardScheme.java:97)
    at com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.enums.EmvCardScheme.<clinit>(EmvCardScheme.java:32)
    at com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.parser.EmvParser.readWithAID(EmvParser.java:277)
    at com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.parser.EmvParser.readEmvCard(EmvParser.java:120)
    at com.github.devnied.emvpcsccard.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

I've added **commons-lang-2.6.jar** & **commons-lang3-3.1-sources.jar** in **libs** and **classpath**

**Main class:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws CardException {
    Main pcsc = new Main();
    CardTerminal ct = pcsc.selectCardTerminal();
    Card c = null;
    if (ct != null) {
        c = pcsc.establishConnection(ct);
        CardChannel channel = c.getBasicChannel();
        PcscProvider provider = new PcscProvider(channel);
        EmvParser parser = new EmvParser(provider, false);
        parser.readEmvCard();
        c.disconnect(false);
    }
}
```

I have referred to the following links:

- [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils from BaseClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781746/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-lang-stringutils-from-basec)
- [Struts 2 framework demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681530/struts-2-framework-demo)
- http://apache-commons.680414.n4.nabble.com/lang-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache-commons-lang-StringUtils-Exception-td3735881.html

Comment: How exactly are you running it?

Comment: I got this error for selenium, i noticed that i added some files manually & some with maven, wich caused this error.. So probably a problem with the compatibility between selenium and htmlDriver (in my case)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> I have added commons-lang-2.6.jar & commons-lang3-3.1-sources.jar...

Here's your problem:  `commons-lang-2.6.jar` doesn't contain the `org.apache.commons.lang3` package, since that's part of version 3, and `commons-lang3-3.1-sources.jar` contains the source code, not the byte code.

You need to include `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` instead.

Comment: which dependency is it?

Comment: @Gobliins The [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) home page has instructions to download it directly, or include it as a maven dependency.

Comment: ah yes i found it i forgot to remove the comment sry

Comment: I have <version>3.3.2</version> of commons-lang3 in pom. This did not solve the issue. I still get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.   Here is the code which has this error  if (StringUtils.equals(blah.getHaha().getLaugh(), "hehe")).

Comment: @MBK In the comments here isn't a great place to try to ask a question.  If this answer didn't help you, it may be because you have a different problem than the OP.  Try posting your own question, including your code and pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks, @azurefrog. The provided solution worked for me. Cheers!!

Answer (score 17):

If you're using **Maven**, put this inside your `pom.xml` file:

Maven Central  Repository for [Commons Lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven Central Repository for [Apache Commons Lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

---

> #### Don't forget: Update Maven Project

---

#### Apache Commons Lang ™ Dependency Information

Last Published: 2 March 2021 | Version: 3.12

#### Apache Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Apache Buildr

```
'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12'
```

Apache Ivy

```
<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.12">
  <artifact name="commons-lang3" type="jar" />
</dependency>
```

Groovy Grape

```
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.12')
)
```

Gradle/Grails

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12'
```

Scala SBT

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.12"
```

Leiningen

```
[org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 "3.12"]
```

---

#### Reference:

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/dependency-info.html

Comment: Or Gradle -- compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'

Comment: I have added below dependency and my problem get resolved.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yo adding the below and update maven project worked like a charm:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding below worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When everything else is correct, rarely jar file gets corrupted. Ensure you don't see error something like below while compiling

```
[ERROR] error reading 
C:\Users\Mohan\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.7\commons-lang3-3.7.jar; 
ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in IJ version 2016 after updating it to 2018.3.4 and clicking "Generate sources and update folders for all projects" at Maven options tab the issue went away

[image: IJ Maven tab at IJ 2018.3.4]