# NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils after self-tests on Google Play (developer console) on Android 4.4 Kit-Kat?

Tags: android, google-play, android-4.4-kitkat, apache-commons

Please, help me to understand. 
I uploaded the application on GooglePlay. There is a self-tests.

In 6 cases, the tests are failed with a strange error that I do not understand and do not know how to fix it. Who has ideas - how to fix it?
All phones with Android Kit-Kat 4.4 completed the test with fail.

[image]

Tests on other versions were successful.
I tried to simulate this problem, start his on the emulator with the same parameters. On the emulator with version 4.4 everything works.

Some information from provided log.

```
10-30 11:39:56.270: D/dalvikvm(14412): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0116
10-30 11:39:56.270: I/dalvikvm(14412): Could not find method org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replace, referenced from method com.jdev.tutor.common.DbHelper.synchronizeRatingsWithDb
10-30 11:39:56.270: W/dalvikvm(14412): VFY: unable to resolve static method 63447: Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils;.replace (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
10-30 11:39:56.270: D/dalvikvm(14412): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
10-30 11:39:56.287: I/PhenotypeFlagCommitter(8050): Experiment Configs successfully retrieved for com.google.android.gms.ocr
10-30 11:39:56.307: D/AndroidRuntime(14412): Shutting down VM
10-30 11:39:56.308: W/dalvikvm(14412): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41733d40)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412): Process: com.jdev.tutor, PID: 14412
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at com.jdev.tutor.common.Commons.checkStorages(Commons.java:87)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at com.jdev.tutor.SplashScreen.init(SplashScreen.java:117)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at com.jdev.tutor.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:66)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access0(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-30 11:39:56.313: E/AndroidRuntime(14412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504174/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-lang3-stringutils

Comment: I think you inattentively read the question.
All work on other versions. Not only runs on that version. And must understand why it should work with the old version and does not work with the new.